# Editing the landing page of a Ruby site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need a bit of help with a Ruby site. It was developed by an agency that closed its doors and now I'm the only left to maintain it. It uses a custom Ruby on Rails (I assume?) CMS. I only need to edit one line of static text but have no experience with Ruby at all. It's in a separate div but the page is generated on the fly and I have no idea where the text is pulled from. No amount of grepping yielded anything. Only thing I tracked down is that one of the slices has a line like

```
<div class="vcard"><%= textilize(slice.address) %></div>
```

This is where I need to change things but I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you have slices table in your database ? If yes it comes from that and column address.

Comment: can you add more code ?

Comment: No. It uses a mongodb database and none of the collections are called slices or anything similar to that. Yes I can edit it, they gave me SSH access to the server.

Comment: If it's not a collection, then it might be a method. Can you find out where `slice` is being declared in the code?

Comment: Can you paste the entire code of that view file, I assume slice might  be a  local variable or method which must be a part of a loop, this part of code must be inside that loop.What is the exact change you want to make?Please elaborate

Comment: It's a proprietary CMS, not sure if I can paste the entire code without giving anything away. They changed their opening hours and the only place it cannot be edited via the backend is the landing page.

Comment: You could try looking around in the DB. If its a value there then changing it in the DB would be better.

Comment: Apparently slices are separate classes. Each has an app/slices/[name_of_slice]/[name_of_slice].rb and then this particular one has three field: entries, on of which is the one I'm trying to change. Guess it's in the db after all?

Comment: Can you modify that to `<%= slice.inspect %>` just to debug? It might give you some more context into what it is, what other properties it has

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to fix it in the meantime. I made a complete dump of the MongoDB database, edited it locally with a GUI then replaced it on the server. Hack job, I know, but it worked.